# Ajax call inside of function

Tags: javascript, ajax, oracle, function

I am working inside of an Oracle package. I am trying to use an AJAX call to call a procedure from a button click. The ajax call is inside of a function. I am not getting any syntax errors from Oracle or when I'm using the browsers debug mode so I'm not sure what the problem is. Function is below.

```
htp.p('
function ApplyTest(_ht) {
     var _inst  = "";
     var _pidm = '||v_web_pidm||';
     var _inst = document.getElementById("Test").value;
        alert("Heat Ticket value is: " + _ht);
        alert("the instance is: " + _inst);
     var resp = confirm("Are you sure you want patch applied to TEST8?");
     if (resp == true) { 
        alert ("user pidm is: " + _pidm);

        return $.ajax ({
             type: "POST",
             cache: false,
             dataType: "json",
             url: "gyapatch.p_update",
             data: {"v_instance" : _inst, "v_ht" : _ht},
             success : function(data) { alert("success"); }
        });

        alert("Got here");
        alert("value: " + _inst);

        window.location.reload;
        alert("got to the end");
     } else {
        return;
     } 
   } 
');
```

code for the button is:

```
<button name="TestApply" id = "Test" onclick="ApplyTest('||val_patch.heat_ticket||')" type="button" value="T">Apply to TEST8</button>'
```

When I try to return the ajax call nothing is happening and I can't even reach the "Got Here" alert. When I remove the "return" keyword, I can reach the alerts but either way, nothing is happening. GYAPATCH.p_update is the package/procedure I wish to have executed when this is ran

I'm not sure what the problem is. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's up with the syntax? Disregarding that, `return` will exit the function, so you naturally won't see the alerts down there. If the ajax call is successful, you should see the `success` alert; if you don't, chances are the request fails. Did you check the browser's network tab? You should see the ajax request there.

Comment: You are returning from the applytest function on the line that initiates the ajax request, so any code after that won’t execute.  Ajax/async coding is tricky and a bit counterintuitive if you’re not used to it.  I suggest you look at a few simple examples here on SO or google.

Comment: You need to put everything that should happen after the AJAX request in the `success:` function.

Comment: I will probably have to research a little more. There are no errors, no warnings or issues from the console, network, or debugger @Barmar: That makes sense. I do have an alert that says success in the "Success" function, but even that is not firing..hmm

Comment: `window.location.reload()` reloads the page, so any scripts from the previous page load are stopped.

Answer (score 0):

So after a couple of hours, I had figured out the problem. This was more of a learning lesson as the issue was pretty simple. I needed to remember that I was working inside of an Oracle database AND also using WebTailor. The code posted above is correct. It turns out that the procedure I was trying to call (p_update) was not registered.

WebTailor allows you to build web applications utilizing Banner. In WebTailor, any pages that are used (usually stemming from a package.procedure), need to be registered or else they are not recognized.

I found this while debugging. Under the Network tab in my debugger, I noticed that when I click my button, I am getting a 404 error when my package.procedure is called. So I then realized it couldn't find my package and then proceeded to check if it was registered. This was a simple, silly error on my part. I am grateful for the feedback, but this will probably serve as a learning lesson or reminder to anyone trying to use ajax while working with Banner data.